# Homogenize use of single and double digit numbers in string

Tags: r, string, data.table, data-management

I have a very large data.table in which (a large number of) items are defined by strings including text and numbers.

```
library(data.table)    
dd <- data.table(x = c("A4","A4","A4","A14","A14","A14","B4","B4","B4"),y = c("A4","A14","B4","A4","A14","B4","A4","A14","B4"), z = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

x   y   z
A4  A4  1
A4  A14 2
A4  B4  3
A14 A4  4
A14 A14 5
A14 B4  6
B4  A4  7
B4  A14 8
B4  B4  9
```

**Numbers can be single or double digit** and therefore R will order them always according to the first digit in the number (A14 before A4). Mixedsort can handle this. However, when I reshape the long data to wide

```
wide <- dcast(dd, x ~ y, value.var = "z")
```

R is applying again the ordering according to the basic ordering rule.

```
x    A14  A4  B4
A14  5    4   6
A4   2    1   3
B4   8    7   9
```

I need however the original ordering for following matrix calculations. Is there any efficient way to rename string + single digits to string + double digits (A4 -> A04) or another approach I have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another, and probably the easiest, option is to use `mixedorder` from the `gtools`-package:

```
wide <- dcast(dd, x ~ y, value.var = "z")[gtools::mixedorder(x)]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > wide
>      x A14 A4 B4
> 1:  A4   2  1  3
> 2: A14   5  4  6
> 3:  B4   8  7  9
> ```

If you also want to get the column order set the same way, you can additionally use `setcolorder`:

```
setcolorder(wide, c(1, gtools::mixedorder(names(wide)[-1]) + 1))
```

which then gives:

> ```
> > wide
>      x A4 A14 B4
> 1:  A4  1   2  3
> 2: A14  4   5  6
> 3:  B4  7   8  9
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sprintf()` to prepad numbers with 0s

```
sprintf("%s%02.0d", "A",  1:20)
# [1] "A01" "A02" "A03" "A04" "A05" "A06" "A07" "A08" "A09" "A10" "A11" "A12" "A13" "A14" "A15" "A16" "A17" "A18" "A19" "A20"
```

Comment: I believe it will be better to use a integer format such as `"%s%02d"`. Upvote, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `0`s to your data with

```
dd[nchar(x) == 2, x := paste0(substr(x, 1, 1), 0, substr(x, 2, 2))]
dd[nchar(y) == 2, y := paste0(substr(y, 1, 1), 0, substr(y, 2, 2))]

#      x   y z
# 1: A04 A04 1
# 2: A04 A14 2
# 3: A04 B04 3
# 4: A14 A04 4
# 5: A14 A14 5
# 6: A14 B04 6
# 7: B04 A04 7
# 8: B04 A14 8
# 9: B04 B04 9
```

Or, if you need to apply to more columns:

```
to.change <- c('x', 'y')

dd[, (to.change) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(nchar(x) > 2, x
                                                   , paste0(substr(x, 1, 1), 0, substr(x, 2, 2))))
   , .SDcols = to.change]
```

Answer (score 2):

No additional zeros required in this solution.

```
# Data frame
df <- data.frame(x = c("A4","A4","A4","A14","A14","A14","B4","B4","B4"),
                 y = c("A4","A14","B4","A4","A14","B4","A4","A14","B4"), 
                 z = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Reorder columns and rows using `mixedsort`. 
wide <- dcast(df, x ~ y,value.var   = "z") %>% 
  select(x, mixedsort(unique(df$x))) %>% 
  slice(match(x, mixedsort(unique(df$x))))
```

gives,

```
#     x A4 A14 B4
# 1  A4  1   2  3
# 2 A14  4   5  6
# 3  B4  7   8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider implementing this order directly in the data through factors, so you don't have to fix it with data wrangling later.

if you already have these unique values sorted somewhere you won't need `mixedorder` not `mixedsort`, just convert them as factors then.

Else you can get the order back :

```
library(gtools)
dd[,1:2] <- lapply(dd[,1:2],function(x) factor(x, mixedsort(unique(x))))
```

And proceed normally:

```
dcast(dd, x ~ y, value.var = "z")
#      x A4 A14 B4
# 1:  A4  1   2  3
# 2: A14  4   5  6
# 3:  B4  7   8  9
```